# Converting shapefiles using OGR2GUI

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, tab

I am trying to convert a MapInfo .TAB file to a Shapefile while setting the projection of the target to NAD83 UTM Zone 19. The latest version of OGR seems to not have this projection available in the drop down for the target file. There are other options for NAD83 but when I check the output files in ArcCatalog they seem to be projecting in a geographic coordinate system.

Does anyone know if NAD83 UTM Sone 19 is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ogr2gui app seems to read from data\gcs.csv for the Projection drop down dialog. You can edit that file, only including the common SR for the US. When I renamed data/pcs.csv to data\gcs.csv, all the UTM zones where presented in the drop down.

**Edit:**
You can either rename the pcs.csv file into gcs.csv for getting a full list of projections or you can make your own shortened list that contains just your favorite projections by picking the corresponding lines from the pcs.csv which is a simple text file with header line on the top followed by the coordinate system definitions as follows:

```
"COORD_REF_SYS_CODE","COORD_REF_SYS_NAME","UOM_CODE","SOURCE_GEOGCRS_CODE","COORD_OP_CODE","COORD_OP_METHOD_CODE","SHOW_CRS","DEPRECATED","COORD_SYS_CODE","PARAMETER_CODE_1","PARAMETER_VALUE_1","PARAMETER_UOM_1","PARAMETER_CODE_2","PARAMETER_VALUE_2","PARAMETER_UOM_2","PARAMETER_CODE_3","PARAMETER_VALUE_3","PARAMETER_UOM_3","PARAMETER_CODE_4","PARAMETER_VALUE_4","PARAMETER_UOM_4","PARAMETER_CODE_5","PARAMETER_VALUE_5","PARAMETER_UOM_5","PARAMETER_CODE_6","PARAMETER_VALUE_6","PARAMETER_UOM_6","PARAMETER_CODE_7","PARAMETER_VALUE_7","PARAMETER_UOM_7"
2000,"Anguilla 1957 / British West Indies Grid",9001,4600,19942,9807,1,0,4400,8801,0,9102,8802,-62,9102,8805,0.9995,9201,8806,400000,9001,8807,0,9001,,,,,,
2001,"Antigua 1943 / British West Indies Grid",9001,4601,19942,9807,1,0,4400,8801,0,9102,8802,-62,9102,8805,0.9995,9201,8806,400000,9001,8807,0,9001,,,,,,
2002,"Dominica 1945 / British West Indies Grid",9001,4602,19942,9807,1,0,4400,8801,0,9102,8802,-62,9102,8805,0.9995,9201,8806,400000,9001,8807,0,9001,,,,,,
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I did not find any documentation about the meaning and importance of the gcs.csv file and it is great that it gets documented here. I deleted my answer and edited yours by adding a sample of the .csv file. I hope you don't mind.